# auto convert dictionary into list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What would be the easiest way to automatic convert the filter[X]... keys/values of the following dictionary to a list of (nested) dictionaries.

```
{'filter[0][data][type]': u'string',
 'filter[0][data][value]': u'T',
 'filter[0][field]': u'company',
 'filter[1][data][comparison]': u'lt',
 'filter[1][data][type]': u'numeric',
 'filter[1][data][value]': u'100',
 'filter[1][field]': u'price',
 'filter[2][data][comparison]': u'gt',
 'filter[2][data][type]': u'numeric',
 'filter[2][data][value]': u'10',
 'filter[2][field]': u'price',
 'limit': u'10',
 'page': u'1',
 'sort': u'[{"property":"company","direction":"ASC"}]',
 'start': u'0'}
```

The result I want would look like:

```
[
  {'data': {'type': 'string', 'value': 'T'}, 'field': 'company'},
  {'data': {'comparison': 'lt', 'type': 'numeric', 'value': 100},
   'field': 'price'},
  {'data': {'comparison': 'gt', 'type': 'numeric', 'value': 10},
   'field': 'price'}
]
```

The initial dictonary is from Pylons passed from an extjs grid filter plugin GET request

There is also an option in extjs grid filter to have the filter json encoded so I end up with:

```
{ 'filter': u'[{"type":"string","value":"T","field":"company"},{"type":"numeric","comparison":"lt","value":100,"field":"price"},{"type":"numeric","comparison":"gt","value":10,"field":"price"}]',
 'limit': u'10',
 'page': u'1',
 'sort': u'[{"property":"company","direction":"ASC"}]',
 'start': u'0'}
```

But again I have not idea how to convert this automatic to python list and dict.

I do not know beforehand the amount of filters for the query so with the created list of dictionaries I can loop over the list and automatic generate an sql query. (though maybe there is a better way to do this?)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: I thought it was obvious what I wanted to achieve, but looking at the fist answer this was not the case so I updated the question and hope it is better now.

Comment: Please include the initial dictionary as well, in python format. You could use the `pprint` module to create a nicely formatted example (`import pprint; pprint.pprint(filter)`).

Comment: If I understand your input example correctly, then you *already* have the data in the 'correct' format.

Comment: But I have no clue how to to this. It seems with PHP this is done with one line of code to return an array: `$filters = isset($_REQUEST['filter']) ? $_REQUEST['filter'] : null;`

Comment: Found a solution, Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: pass the filter as json encoded and then is just a matter of using json.loads() and I get a list of dictionaries.

```
>>> import json

>>> dict = {'filter': u'[{"type":"string","value":"T","field":"company"},{"type":"numeric","comparison":"lt","value":100,"field":"price"},{"type":"numeric","comparison":"gt","value":10,"field":"price"}]',
 'limit': u'10',
 'page': u'1',
 'sort': u'[{"property":"company","direction":"ASC"}]',
 'start': u'0'}

>>> json.loads(dict['filter'])

[{u'field': u'company', u'type': u'string', u'value': u'T'},
 {u'comparison': u'lt',
  u'field': u'price',
  u'type': u'numeric',
  u'value': 100},
 {u'comparison': u'gt', u'field': u'price', u'type': u'numeric', u'value': 10}]
```